# getting RecursionError when using Getter and Setter decorators

Tags: python, class, recursion, decorator

I am currently working on a Multi-Arm Bandit Model and I want to be able to set the epsilon (numerical value between 0 and 1). I am trying to use the Getter and Setter decorators:

```
@property
    def epsilon(self):
        """Return epsilon"""
        return self.epsilon

    @epsilon.setter
    def epsilon(self, epsilon):
        """Manually update model epsilon parameter"""
        if 0 <= epsilon <= 1:
            self.epsilon = epsilon
        else:
            logger.error("Epsilon must be numeric value between 0 and 1")
```

But I am getting a

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

error. Not sure how to prevent this. I already tried putting a `Return` after the if but still same error.

Comment: `self.epsilon` -> this is the `epsilon` property! Use `self._epsilon` or any other name to denote inner storage of the value which `self.epsilon` returns/sets

Comment: Great it works. Thanks!